# zend framework 2.0 fill option from database

Tags: zend-framework2

i have my application based in ZendSkeletonApplication , now i want  create to relationship between my models so:

```
user            portal
id              id
firstName       name
lastName        url
........
portal_Id
```

I want to fill my select-option in the user form with database values

```
<?php
namespace Register\Form;

use Zend\Captcha\AdapterInterface as CaptchaAdapter;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Element;


class UserForm extends Form
{
    protected $portalTable;

    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct('user');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setAttribute('class', 'form-horizontal');

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'id',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'hidden',
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'type' => 'Select',
                'name' => 'portal_id',
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Portal',
                        'empty_option' => 'Seleccione un portal',
                        'value_options' => array(
                                '1' => 'portal 1',
                                '2' => 'portal 2',
                                '3' => 'portal 3',
                                //i want option from database with 
                        ),

                )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'firstName',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'text',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'First Name',
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'lastName',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'text',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Last Name',
                ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'login',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'text',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Login',
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'password',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'password',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Password',
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'password_repeat',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'password',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'password (repeat)',
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'email',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'text',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Email',
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Csrf',
                'name' => 'csrf',
                'options' => array(
                        'csrf_options' => array(
                                'timeout' => 600
                        )
                )
        ));

        $this->add( array(
                'type' => 'Captcha',
                'name' => 'captcha',
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Please verify you are human.',
                        'captcha' => array('class' => 'Dumb',
                        ),
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'submit',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'submit',
                        'value' => 'Go',
                        'id' => 'submitbutton',
                ),
        ));
    }
}
```

in this part i want fill select from database

```
$this->add(array(
                'type' => 'Select',
                'name' => 'portal_id',
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Portal',
                        'empty_option' => 'Seleccione un portal',
                        'value_options' => array(
                                '1' => 'portal 1',
                                '2' => 'portal 2',
                                '3' => 'portal 3',
                                //i want option from database with 
                        ),

                )
        ));
```

sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written an in-depth blog "[Zend\Form\Element\Select and Database-Values](https://web.archive.org/web/20160316093620/http://samminds.com/2013/03/zendformelementselect-and-database-values/)" about this topic. Basically though, this is what you have to do:

Basically all you have to do is Query the Database inside your Form for the Data. For this you need the DB-Adapter to be available inside your Form, which is done by Dependency-Injection. Since the DB-Adapter is `required` for your Form to function correctly, i'd suggest Setter-Injection.

Inside your `getServiceConfig()` do this:

```
return array('factories' => array(
    'namespace-form-formname' => function($sm) {
        $dbA  = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        $form = new \Namespace\Form\Formname($dbA);

        return $form;
    }
));
```

This will inject the `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter` into your form, which should already be valid though other configuration. Then you need to modify your form code a little bit:

```
public function __construct(\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter $dbA) {
    parent::__construct('form-name');

    // Do the DB-Query here. You got the DB-Adapter
    // http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.db.adapter.html
    $selectArray =  array(
        'key' => 'value',
        'key' => 'value',
        'key' => 'value',
    ); // obviously, this is just a fake-$selectArray demonstrating 
       // what the output of your Queries should be

    // Add your Form Elements here
    // use $selectArray as value_options of your desired select element
}
```

And that's basically it. Sadly i can't give you an concrete example, as i've never worked with `Zend\Db`, but i assume this will get you started.

PS: In your controller, call the form like this:

```
$form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('namespace-form-formname');
```

Comment: What part do you not understand?

Comment: how do I include an option of another Class Table filled in my form. In this example, i need include select filled portals into form user, but I do not how to include :/

Comment: I just pointed out how you get the DB Adapter into a FORM. Instead of DB Adapter you can also input a tablegateway or whatever way you prefer to access a database.

Comment: with the gateway I think it's easier because the queries performed ClassTable so .. how could I do that?

Comment: see $sm->get('\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter') - instead of that you get your tablegateway

Comment: ok..look the part where i want fill select from database. you say add $sm->get('\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter') (in my ClassForm) ??

Comment: I know my answer is abstract, but for now this must suffice, sorry. I'll write an detailled answer/blog sometime later. Please carefully read my answer and understand this. I feel like it can be enough.

Comment: @andres Please refer to my newest blogpost, this covers the whole topic much more in-depth

Answer (score 0):

```
Try:
// add code on controller
$arrPortalId = array();
$results = array('1' => 'portal 1', '2' => 'portal 2', '3' => 'portal 3',); // this part change your database value
foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
$arrPortalId[$key] = $va;
}
$dataParams['portalId'] = $arrPortalId;
$form = new UserForm($dataParams);

 <?php
namespace Register\Form;

use Zend\Captcha\AdapterInterface as CaptchaAdapter;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Element;


class UserForm extends Form
{
    protected $portalTable;

    public function __construct($params = array())
    {   $name = isset($params['name'])?$params['name']:'';
        parent::__construct('user');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setAttribute('class', 'form-horizontal');

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'id',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'hidden',
                ),
        ));
    $portalId = (isset($params['portalId']) && count($params['portalId']) > 0)?$params['portalId']:array();
        $this->add(array(
                'type' => 'Select',
                'name' => 'portal_id',
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Portal',
                        'empty_option' => 'Seleccione un portal',
                        'value_options' => $portalId,

                )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'firstName',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'text',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'First Name',
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'lastName',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'text',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Last Name',
                ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'login',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'text',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Login',
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'password',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'password',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Password',
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'password_repeat',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'password',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'password (repeat)',
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'email',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'text',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Email',
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Csrf',
                'name' => 'csrf',
                'options' => array(
                        'csrf_options' => array(
                                'timeout' => 600
                        )
                )
        ));

        $this->add( array(
                'type' => 'Captcha',
                'name' => 'captcha',
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Please verify you are human.',
                        'captcha' => array('class' => 'Dumb',
                        ),
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'submit',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'submit',
                        'value' => 'Go',
                        'id' => 'submitbutton',
                ),
        ));
    }
}
```